# Photoshop CS6 export to RGB 565 format

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-format

I googled this a bit and found an [older post on the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1904017) but that's for Photoshop CS3.

[image: Photoshop BMP RGB 565]

I was looking for the Advanced Mode option but couldn't find it.
Is it still possible to save a bitmap in RGB 565 format from Photoshop CS6 (even with scripting) ?
If so, how ?

Comment: Very useful question: RGB 565 format is the bitmap format used in the [.Net Micro Framework](http://www.netmf.com/net-micro-framework-version-40-sdk-overview.aspx) (at least that's what brought me here, eventually), other formats are converted to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your image **must** be in RGB mode, then <kbd>File > Save As...</kbd>

Change the 'Format:' to <kbd>`BMP (*.BMP;*.RLE;*.DIB)`</kbd> and click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

In the "BMP Options dialog the comes up, click the <kbd>Advanced Modes</kbd> button.

Voila! There is your **R5 G8 B5** option.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: (N.B. It's 565, not 585.) For me it was not enough to have the image in RGB mode, I had to further set it to 8 bits per channel as explained by Scott [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/36391/4078)